# Is there any way to trim Column Headers?

Tags: ssis

I have a simple SSIS package which gets data from a SQL source and outputs to a .dat file.
Now am having two problems in the output.

--> Am getting spaces in the Column header

```
FirstName                             , LastName                ,......
```

--> Am gettting the same for the data

```
Mike                 , Jung            ,......
```

I fixed the second problem by using the trim function.

Is there a way to fix the column headers so they don't have any space? like

```
Firstname,LastName,.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the column names in Source table if you are allowed to do so using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table and can proceed with the data flow task. But, this will change (trim) the column names in Source table as well..